# ST_ClosestPoint equal, but not touching

Tags: postgis

I have two polygons where one should cover the other.  They were created in qgis using snapping, however when I checked their topology with postgis it turned out one point on the inner polygon registered as outside the covering polygon.  This seems to regularly happen when I create an inner polygon with an edge that lies on an outer polygon.

When I use ST_Equals on the point supposedly outside the polygon and the closest point on the outer polygon it returns true, but when I check whether the polygon and the point are touching it returns false.

Here's the query I'm running:

```
--CTE with points that are outside the outer polygon (only one in this specific case)
WITH outsidepoints AS (
SELECT dump.geom 
FROM (
    SELECT geom, 
           ST_Covers((SELECT geom from zone WHERE gid = 403), geom) 
    FROM ST_DumpPoints((SELECT geom from zone WHERE gid = 416))
    ) AS dump 
WHERE st_covers = false
)

--Check if closest point on outer polygon and "outside" point on inner polygon are equal
--Check if "outside" point touches outer polygon
SELECT ST_Equals(geom, ST_ClosestPoint((SELECT geom from zone WHERE gid = 403), geom)), 
       ST_Touches(geom, (SELECT geom from zone WHERE gid = 403)) 
FROM outsidepoints
```

The result is T, F

Is this some kind of floating point error?  Is there a tolerance parameter I need to set for these calculations?

Comment: Could you add WKT of the polygon and the point?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to create a working example of this problem where the polygons are created from text, but I haven't been successful.  After converting the problematic polygons using ST_AsText and then remaking them using ST_GeomFromText, the problem seems to be fixed.

So while it's not exactly efficient, my current solution is to recreate every polygon.